# Immutable.js prints a warning on accessing .length of a List

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I've searched everywhere but don't seem to find the solution.

When mapping my data, I want to get the length of a List I have in my state:

```
state.substate.get('myList').length
```

But it throws a warning telling me to use the `size` property or `count()` function and can't figure out how to use it on a state property I am getting.

How should I be doing it?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

ImmutableJS List extends [`Collection.Indexed`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Collection/Indexed), which have two ways to return to current size (length) of the collection:

- The member [`size`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Collection/Indexed) -> `state.substate.get('myList').size`
- The method [`count()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Collection/count) -> `state.substate.get('myList').count()`

Comment: I've got the answer, I was not transforming my array into a List before setting it into myList, it works now :)